# Multi-params GET request in MongoDB + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB + Node.js and I need to create a GET request which by taking differents ids given by user, returns all the rows which have them in the table. For example:

Main table:

```
| id | zone | areas | colors |
| 1  | 1,2,3| 11,7  | 6,9,23 |  <-- String
| 2  |   3  | 11,7,9|   3    |  <-- String
```

Ok, user select in the UI as filter rows where zone = [3] and areas = [11,7].
Both rows contains those ids so I have to show both of them. The problem is:

- How can I compare them since I receive from body a JSON and elements
  in DB are strings?

  ```
      const multiKey = db.get('app');
      router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
       try {

       // take the collection
       const collection = await multiKey.find({});

       let collectionRows = [];
       // insert into array and transform them in strings
       collectionRows.push(JSON.stringify(collection));

       let filter = [];
       // put filters into array
       filter.push(JSON.stringify(req.filter));

       let rows = [];

       // if element contains a filter, take the row --> DOESN'T WORK
       collectionRows.forEach(element => {
           if(element.includes(filter)){
               rows.push(element);
           }
       });

       if(!rows) next();
       return res.json(rows);


        } catch (error) {
          next(error);
        }
      });
  ```

Comment: Why the `find` filter is empty?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon This way I get the full collection.. or at least this is what i get if i console.log() collection

Comment: Could you use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#nested-array) operator?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Could you be more specific and maybe motivate your answer with an example? Thanks!